# TypeScript interface: function as property - or - this in interface implementations

Tags: function, properties, interface, typescript

My problem is with functions in interfaces and the `this` keyword in the implementation.

Assume the following scenario:

I've got a class which implements a specific interface. The interface may be defined as following:

```
module Contracts
{
    export interface ISomeInterface
    {
        Foo: () => void;
    }
}
```

The implementation may look like this:

```
module MyClasses
{
    export class SomeClass implements Contracts.ISomeInterface
    {
        public SomeValue: string = "Some fancy value";

        public Foo() 
        {
            alert(this.SomeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This works when I call it from the instance, like this:

```
var someClass = new MyClasses.SomeClass();
someClass.Foo();
```

Now, due to some circumstances the function is not being called like this, but within another context, causing `this` to be something completely different, resulting in `this.SomeValue` being undefined.

I've learned that when you want to access `this` correctly when a function is called within another context, you use the fat arrow like this:

```
public Foo = () =>
{
    alert(this.SomeValue);
}
```

*(More info: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions)*

But this doesn't satisfy the interface. Foo is recognized as a property in the class, but the interface defines it as a method. Makes sense.

So how do I fix this the nice way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing for you to do is to pass a bound function to your callback (or whatever).

For example:

```
let a: SomeClass = new SomeClass();
let boundFoo = a.Foo.bind(a);
boundFoo(); // this should be as you intended
```

[More about the `bind` function in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

---

### Edit

I checked [your code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ISomeInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0Aclass%20SomeClass%20implements%20ISomeInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20SomeValue%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22Some%20fancy%20value%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20Foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert(this.SomeValue)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D) and it seems ok.
The class implements the interface and the compiler does not complain.

Comment: Strange... My Visual Studio 2015 uses TypeScript 1.8.30.0 but wouldn't let me compile this. Anyways, using the bind function worked like a charm. Thanks!